# Can I bind HTML to a WPF Web Browser Control?

Tags: wpf, browser

Suppose I have a property HTML (string). Can I bind that to a WPF WebBrowser control? There is the Source property where I need a URI, but if I have a HTML string in memory I want to render, can I do that? I am using MVVM, so I think its harder to use methods like `webBrowser1.NavigateToString()` etc? cos I won't know the control name?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control) question.

To summarize, first you create an Attached Property for WebBrowser

```
public class BrowserBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Html",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BrowserBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnHtmlChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(WebBrowser))]
    public static string GetHtml(WebBrowser d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHtml(WebBrowser d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowser = dependencyObject as WebBrowser;
        if (webBrowser != null)
            webBrowser.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string ?? "&nbsp;");
    }
}
```

And then you can Bind to your html string and NavigateToString will be called everytime your html string changes

```
<WebBrowser local:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding MyHtmlString}" />
```

Comment: This is a nice trick. However when trying to embed a WebBrowser inside a DataTemplate (for instance, when templating combobox's item) it doesn't seem to work (for some reason the OnHtmlChanged is get raised twice, the second time with null).

Comment: @tomer I had the same problem so I just changed e.NewValue as string to e.NewValue as string ?? "&nbsp;". I edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: @Fredrik Hedblad -- how can I use your aswer but insteas bind MyHtmlString to a htm document added to the project? This document would contain the html that i want displayed.