# control style in WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf

I have an error return string that is sometimes plain text and sometimes HTML. My idea is to display that in a WebBrowser control. I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202961/can-i-bind-html-to-a-wpf-web-browser-contro) that showed how to assign a string as content for a webBrowser. This is my XAML:

```
<WebBrowser
            local:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding ElementName=resultListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Details}" 
            Width="400" MinHeight="50" Margin="0">
        </WebBrowser>
```

It works fine but plain strings are displayed in some times roman font. Is there a way to inject a style sheet into the WebBrowser control? Or is there a better solution to my problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your attached property's code:

```
static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = dependencyObject as WebBrowser;
    webBrowser.LoadCompleted += WebBrowserOnLoadCompleted;
    if (webBrowser != null)
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string ?? "&nbsp;");
}

private static void WebBrowserOnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
{
    var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;

    if (webBrowser != null)
    {
        var document = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

        if (document != null)
        {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head").OfType<mshtml.HTMLHeadElement>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (head != null)
            {
                var styleSheet = (mshtml.IHTMLStyleSheet)document.createStyleSheet("", 0);
                styleSheet.cssText = "* { background-color: purple; " +
                                     "    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; " +
                                     " /* set whatever CSS rule you want */ }";
            }
        }

        webBrowser.LoadCompleted -= WebBrowserOnLoadCompleted;
    }
}
```

You have to include `Microsoft.mshtml` reference for this to work.

This attaches a `LoadCompleted` event handler before navigating to the `string`. In the handler it gets the `head` element, creates a new `style` tag and adds the CSS rules you want.