# How to clear WebBrowser control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm using the code from the following link: [Displaying html from string in WPF WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control/2586255)

It works well except when I delete the item containing the html, `e.NewValue` becomes `null` and I get an exception. Is there a way to return the WebBrowser control to a blank screen?

Comment: I found this troubling as well, considering that [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring(v=vs.110).aspx) itself states that "If the *text* parameter is **null**, [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) navigates to a blank document ("about:blank")." Clearly not the case... Also quoted, "**.NET Framework**
Available since 3.0," I'm on 4.0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this. Anyone have anything better?

```
if (wb != null)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null)
        wb.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string);
    else
        wb.Navigate("about:blank");
}
```

**EDIT:**

As poby mentioned in the comments, for .NET 4+ use:

```
if (wb != null)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null)
        wb.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string);
    else
        wb.Navigate((Uri)null);
}
```

Comment: In .Net 3.5:
wb.Navigate(null) 
instead of 
wb.Navigate("about:blank")

Comment: oh cool i'll have to try that out sometime. thanks for the update!

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.0 and `wb.Navigate(null)` is ambiguous for two of the method overloads. Attempting `wb.Navigate(string.Empty)` also fails as `string.Empty` is an invalid Uri. The provided solution sufficed, though instead I checked for `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValue.ToString())`

Comment: For .Net 4 and above, use `wb.Navigate((Uri)null)` avoids the ambiguity and works a charm:)

Answer (score 0):

I just set the WebBrowserLabel's [DocumentText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx) to [string.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty(v=vs.110).aspx).