# How to display an html content inside wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to display HTML content inside the WPF.
Here is my XAML code:

```
<WebBrowser Source="Views/Sample.html"></WebBrowser>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use web browser control.
Hope the below one can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362591/how-to-display-the-string-html-contents-into-webbrowser-control)

Comment: No I need  to add from a folder as source to web browser

Comment: You can use a text reader and get the html from the file and append to the browser control

Comment: See this too [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Comment: `Thanks` is your XAML code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying html from string in WPF WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am updating the answer better

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var exePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var pagesFolder = Directory.GetParent(exePath).Parent.Parent;
        string homePageFullPath = pagesFolder.FullName + "\\Pages\\Home.html";
        WebBrowser1.Source = new Uri(homePageFullPath);
    }

}
```

You need to have the home.html in the bin folder where the wpf exe is located. You can make the "Copy To Output Directory" as "Copy Always"

The above one is working for me.

If the file is in a different folder please have the absolute path

Comment: Could you please get me the error, your code and the file path?

Comment: It's Showing,  Make sure the path or internet address is correct.

Comment: I fear I couldn't help you unless you have some piece of code here. Also could you please copy one of the html to bin folder and try my code by replacing the name? ie  WebBrowser1.Source = new Uri(new System.IO.FileInfo("Home.html").FullName);

Comment: <WebBrowser x:Name="sample"></WebBrowser>
sample.Source = new Uri(new System.IO.FileInfo("View.html").FullName);

This is my code

Comment: Ok could you place the View.html in the bin\Debug folder and try?

Comment: [Code sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ma4y3k08z9vwxyz/WebBrowserControlSample.zip?dl=0) Please download the sample I have created. Still you application is not working then you can share me the sample and I can take a look

Comment: Thanks Its Working, But what should i do if it is inside a folder

Comment: Just give a thought what should do. You have to give the absolute path

Comment: How I am not getting it any where

Comment: My HTML is Inside a View Folder

Comment: I have updated by code .[New code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/miw0v6dxy1ug010/WebBrowserControlSample.zip?dl=0) If this works please make this as answer

Comment: Is it Possible to add javascript to this html

Comment: If the question is got answered could you please accept the answer?

Comment: How to do that.

Comment: You are asking a different question now. Please accept my answer if your initial question was answered. You can post a different question for the 2nd one