# How to properly display ' and " in a WPF WebBrowser that is bound to HTML string

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I followed the answer in

[Displaying html from string in WPF WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585782/displaying-html-from-string-in-wpf-webbrowser-control)

to bind to list of html content, so I'm able to display it in a WPF program I've built. I can't figure out how to get the ' and " to display properly.

Displaying HTML from string in a WebBrowser control doesn't properly display ' or "

Here is my XAML:

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
      <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TitleBrush}"  Margin="50,0">
       <WebBrowser utility:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding SelectedEmail.EmailContent}" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class BrowserBehavior
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Html",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BrowserBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnHtmlChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(WebBrowser))]
    public static string GetHtml(WebBrowser d)
    {
      return (string)d.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHtml(WebBrowser d, string value)
    {
      d.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      WebBrowser webBrowser = dependencyObject as WebBrowser;
      if (webBrowser != null)
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string ?? "&nbsp;");
    }
  }
```

See the link above how with questions. Any help on how to get the ' or " to display would be much appreciate.

I have already tried to replace ' with &apos and &#39 with no results.

Example of Problem:

**We have added several overlay options for the frame line. Each option will allow you to pick either â€œSTDâ€ (Doesnâ€™t auto add butt doors) or â€œBUTTâ€ (Auto adds butt doors).**

Example of Proper Format:

**We have added several overlay options for the frame line. Each option will allow you to pick either "STD" (Doesn't auto add butt doors) or "BUTT" (Auto adds butt doors).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) and simply escape double quotes with an added double quote.

This sample works for me.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang=""en"">
            <body>
            <div>My Test HTML 'single quote', ""double quote""</div>
            </body>
        </html>";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
    }
}
```

If you are reading the HTML from a file you shouldn't need to do anything special.

```
MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myfilepath\myfile.htm"));
```