# How can I render HTML or markdown in a WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, .net-core, markdown

Is there a way to render/show HTML (or Markdown) in a .NET Core WPF Datagrid column / cell ?

I have some text in a database which I would like to add some formatting options to.
I was thinking to add the possibility to format it using markdown.

This text then is displayed in a datagrid using `itemsource = List<myobject>`, and I would like to have it displayed formatted in the datagrid column/cell.

So I used Markdig to generate HTML from the text in the database. This gives me something like:

`<p>This is a text with some <em>emphasis</em></p>`

And this should be displayed like:

This is a text with some *emphasis*

But then I get stuck. It seems like HTML is something alien to WPF.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your comment. I´ve edited the title. I viewed your link but it I´m unable to link it to my issue: I want to display formatted text in a datagrid column / cell. Could you please provide a little more context ?

Comment: I just linked similar question, where OP wants to display HTML and mentioned [FlowDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview). Just an idea to use xaml instead of html.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this with WPF's [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) in a DataGridTemplateColumn.  Some sample code is below.

To get the WebBrowser to display an HTML string you have to call NavigateToString.  I've done this using an attached property as described in [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2586255/4166522).

I've also done some work to remove the disabled scrollbars that the control will put in a cell by default, even if the content fits.  I've used CSS styling to do this, but it's a little hacky.

Note that we are warned that the WebBrowser control is quite heavyweight in terms of memory usage, so you probably wouldn't want to do it this way in a grid with a lot of rows.

[image]

C#:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp14
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CreateProducts();
            this.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Products;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        private void CreateProducts()
        {
            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
            {
                new Product{ID = 1, Html = "HTML with no formatting"},
                new Product{ID = 2, Html= "<h1>This is a <i>test</i> header</h1>"},
                new Product{ID = 3, Html="<p>This is a text with some <em>emphasis</em></p>"},
                new Product{ID = 4, Html="<ul><li>Product 1</li><li>Product 2</li><li>Product 3</li></ul>"}
            };
        }
    }

    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private int id;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ID)));
            }
        }

        private string html;
        public string Html
        {
            get { return html; }
            set
            {
                html = RemoveScrollbars(value);
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Html)));
            }
        }

        private string RemoveScrollbars(string html)
        {
            string before = "<head><style>body{overflow:hidden;}</style></head><body>";
            string after = "</body>";
            return before + html + after;
        }
    }

    public static class BrowserBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Html",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(BrowserBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnHtmlChanged));

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(WebBrowser))]
        public static string GetHtml(WebBrowser d)
        {
            return (string)d.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHtml(WebBrowser d, string value)
        {
            d.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
        }

        static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = d as WebBrowser;
            if (wb != null)
                wb.NavigateToString(e.NewValue as string);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp14"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WebBrowser local:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding Html}" Height="90"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```